# Why won't AnyDice let me store dice rolls in variables?

Tags: anydice

I'm trying to emulate a "Fate-like" distribution that imitates 1d6-1d6.
That's not really the point, so much as I don't understand the error it gives me.

```
function: ff {
  BLUE: d6
  RED: d6
  if BLUE < RED {
    result: BLUE
  }
  if BLUE > RED {
    result: -RED
  }
  result: 0
}

output [ff] named "absolute"
output 1d6 - 1d6 named "1d6-1d6"
output 4d{-1,0,1} named "4dF"
```

[image: A screenshot of an error produced by AnyDice when inserting the above code. It reads: calculation error. Boolean values can only be numbers, but you provided "d{?}". Depending on what you want, you might need to create a function.]

Comment: The code provided doesn't run; can you include the whole "program"? Or, better: can you cut away code to provide a minimal case that exhibits the issue (eg., the last two lines can trivially be removed)?

Comment: [This answer to an earlier question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/57709/how-do-i-find-the-highest-number-rolled-in-a-pool-if-dice-and-the-number-of-tim/65454#65454) goes into some detail on this.

Answer (score 21):

As I noted in [an answer to an earlier question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/57709/how-do-i-find-the-highest-number-rolled-in-a-pool-if-dice-and-the-number-of-tim/65454#65454), a "die" variable in AnyDice represents a certain probability distribution over the integers.*  Every time you use the die in an expression, AnyDice treats it as a *separate, independent* roll with that distribution.

Here's [a simple program to demonstrate this](http://anydice.com/program/6498):

```
DIE: 1d6
output DIE - DIE named "you'd think this should be zero, but it's not..."
```

If `DIE` represented a specific number rolled using `1d6`, then `DIE - DIE` should always be zero.  But it's not, as running the program above will easily demonstrate.

In fact, what's going on is that `DIE` here is just an *alias* for `1d6`, so `DIE - DIE` is the same as `1d6 - 1d6`; i.e. (the distribution of) the difference between two separate `1d6` rolls.

---

<sup>*) AnyDice variables can also store a "collection of dice" such as `3d6`, which in some sense represents a probability distribution not just over single integers but over sequences of them. But only a *very* limited set of such distributions is supported: you can't even have a collection containing dice of two different types, much less a collection of a variable number of dice or a collection of dice whose values are not independent. And if you use such a collection of dice in a context where AnyDice expects a single number (or die), AnyDice will just convert the collection of dice into the probability distribution of their sum.</sup>

---

The fact that your `RED` and `BLUE` variables are probability distributions, rather than fixed numbers, is also why you're getting the error saying that "Boolean values can only be numbers".

(Again, I've mentioned this in a [couple](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/192067/anydice-error-boolean-values-can-only-be-numbers/192071#192071) of [answers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/197916/how-do-you-simulate-dependent-dice-rolls-in-anydice/197921#197921) before, but I quick recap might be useful.)

Basically, the error message means what it says — you can't do something like:

```
if d2 = 1 { \ do something \ } else { \ do something else \ }
```

because AnyDice would have to somehow execute *both* paths, since `d2` can be either 1 or 2, and combine the resulting arbitrary program states into some kind of weird "quantum superposition".  AnyDice is pretty clever, but it's not *that* clever.

What AnyDice *is* just smart enough to do, however, is call a function for every possible number (or sequence) you can roll on a particular die (or a collection of dice) and collect the results of the function back into a "custom die" (i.e. a probability distribution) weighted by their likelihood.

You can use this to "freeze" one or more dice by passing them into a function that expects a number (or a sequence) as a parameter, like this:

```
function: evaluate RED:n and BLUE:n {
  if BLUE < RED {
    result: BLUE
  }
  if BLUE > RED {
    result: -RED
  }
  result: 0
}

output [evaluate d6 and d6]
```

Here, the `:n` after `RED` and `BLUE` in the function definition tells AnyDice that these parameter are supposed to be numbers (not sequences or dice).  When you call the function and pass a die for such a parameter, AnyDice will automatically call the function with every number you could roll on the die and collect the results into a new probability distribution based on the how likely each roll is.

Thus, *inside* the function the *parameters* `RED` and `BLUE` are indeed fixed numbers, and you can use them in `if` conditions just fine.

(And yes, your mechanic indeed [gives exactly the same distribution](https://anydice.com/program/2f9db) of results as simply subtracting one of the dice from the other. That's actually a rather interesting observation!)